# VMware Clarity Wizard: How to make all pages active or clickable

Tags: angularjs, vmware-clarity, clarity

I have a use case where we are opening the Wizard for editing the information which means the user has already saved the information and now he wants to edit or view it. my wizard has 4 pages and I do not want users to go to the pages one by one by clicking on the next button where I want all pages link in enable state and the user should be able to move from any page without clicking on the next button.